# Sql SUM within range

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data, which looks like this. To make it simple, I will display `date` as 'Day' + number

```
Date     ID
-----------
Day1     A
Day1     B
Day1     C  
Day2     A
Day2     A
Day3     A
Day4     B
Day5     A
```

I would like to count how many IDs are in each `date`. However, each date needs to contain all the previous date counts.

Meaning, if user picks range from Day3 to Day5.

```
Date    Count
Day3    Day1+Day2+Day3
Day4    Day1+Day2+Day3+Day4
Day5    Day1+Day2+Day3+Day4+Day5
```

All I can think of is use 'UNION' to add 3 queries for each day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a cumulative sum, which Oracle does support.

Try this:

```
select date, sum(daycnt) over (order by date)
from (select date, count(*) as daycnt
      from t
      where date between DAY_START and DAY_END
      group by t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this stuff out

```
select Dt, count(*)
from
(
 select t2.Date Dt
 from t t1, (select Date from t group by Date) t2
 where t1.Date < t2.Date
)
group by Dt
```